# Is unwillkürlich the opposite of willkürlich?

Tags: meaning, adjective, german-to-english, meaning-in-context, adverb

My dictionary translates *willkürlich* as *arbitrary* and *unwillkürlich* as *involuntary*. I do not understand in what sense these concepts are opposites. Could someone give an example where this becomes evident?

I have these examples from *Der Zauberberg*.

> » 
>   Soll ich humanistisch reden statt menschlich?« (Unwillkürlich dehnte auch er das Wort auf schläfrige Weise, ungefähr wie 
>       jemand, der sich reckt und gähnt.)

Here I think *involuntarily* or *unintentionally* would make sense.

> Er war dreizehn Jahre alt, Untertertianer, ein Junge in kurzen 
>   Hosen, und stand auf dem Schulhof im Gespräch mit einem anderen, ungefähr gleichaltrigen Jungen aus einer anderen Klasse, 
>     - einem Gespräch, das Hans Castorp ziemlich willkürlich vom 
>       Zaune gebrochen hatte, und das ihn, obgleich es seines sachlichen und knapp umschriebenen Gegenstandes wegen nur ganz 
>       kurz sein konnte, doch im höchsten Grade erfreute.

Here in my opinion it would make sense to translate *willkürlich* as *intentionally*, but this would be out of line with my dictionary. Now what about this example:

> Wenn auch außen verklammt, habe ich doch innerlich Wärme gesammelt bei der Bewegung, die ich gemacht, 
>     und so war die Exkursion doch nicht ganz nutzlos, wenn ich 
>     auch umgekommen bin und von der Hütte zur Hütte geschweift . . . ›Umgekommen‹, was ist denn das für ein Ausdruck? Man braucht ihn gar nicht, er ist nicht üblich für das, was 
>              mir zugestoßen, ganz willkürlich setze ich ihn dafür ein, weil 
>                 ich nicht so ganz klar im Kopfe bin; und doch ist es in seiner 
>                 Art ein richtiges Wort, wie mir scheint . . .

Could you translate it as *arbitrarily*? How is it the opposite of *unwillkürlich*? Will the meaning not even be similar if you replace *willkürlich* with *unwillkürlich*?

Comment: take a look at **spontaneous**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Willkürlich* has two different meanings:

- bewusst, vom eigenen Willen gesteuert (voluntary, deliberately)

This one is the exact opposite of *unwillkürlich* (involuntary).

The second meaning,

- auf Willkür beruhend (arbitrary)

is rather different, because the word "Willkür" has shifted in meaning over the years. It used to mean doing something of your own free will and by your own decision, but the meaning has shifted towards doing something without good reason, arbitrarily, just because you want to - for example, it is used to describe the way a dictator would run their country. It is also now a legal term meaning something like "without just cause".

This second meaning is far more common now, and you hardly ever see willkürlich used in the first way anymore. *Unwillkürlich*, which hasn't shifted in meaning, is therefore not the opposite of *willkürlich* in its common modern meaning, although it is the opposite of willkürlich in its original meaning.